# How to guarantee Supervisor-launched script gets killed when daemon stopped?

Tags: python, supervisord

How do you ensure that running `sudo supervisorctl stop myservice` actually stops my service?

I have a Supervisor config like:

```
[program:myprogram]
command=/usr/local/bin/run_script.sh
directory=/usr/local/bin
user=myuser
numprocs=1
process_name=%(program_name)s
stdout_logfile=/var/log/run_script.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/run_script.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopsignal=KILL
```

The file `run_script.sh` does some shell initialization, and then launches a separate Python script, `run_script.py`, which blocks but runs some multiple processes via `joblib.Parallel`.

When I start the daemon, Supervisor launches it fine. However, when I run `sudo supervisorctl stop myprogram`, the daemon never stops, even though Supervisor lists them as stopped. Several minutes later, if I run `ps aux | grep -i run_script`, I can see both the .sh and .py scripts running.

Why is Supervisor unable to stop a daemon?

I've specified the KILL stopsignal. Is there some issue with a Bash script launching a Python script, which itself launches multi-processes, that's stopping Supervisor from being able to properly stop the process?

Answer (score 0):

There's two things happening here.

1. Supervisord knows PID of its immediate children, but not all descendents.
2. We're sending uncatchable KILL (9) rather than TERM (15).

Those two won't get along with one another.

---

Current hierarchy is: bash --> python --> python workers

Now, if it was *just* "bash --> python",
we might address your issue with `exec python myservice.py`,
collapsing the hierarchy down to just a single process.
Initially it would be a bash process with pid 123,
and then a python process, still with pid 123,
thanks to the exec.

But given the workers, that's not sufficient,
we need to dig a bit further.

---

You are complaining "I sent SIGKILL and the Right Thing didn't happen!"

Well, of course it didn't, you didn't
give "myservice" a chance to clean
up its children.

(As I think about it, ending the bash
script with "exec python ..." would be
convenient, as then we have one less
signal handler to worry about.)

Send SIGTERM (15) to your python
process, and verify that it

- catches the signal
- sends SIGTERM to its children
- exits

I would expect that all to happen by
default, but you can certainly write
a TERM handler to debug and to do
any additional cleanup items that
are needed.
There might be a list of children PIDs
handy, or we might want to send
to PID zero, so it's delivered to
everyone in the process group,
just like killpg() would do.

If children are not well behaved,
your custom handler *might* want
to send KILL (9) after a timeout.
I recommend you stick to just TERM
if you can get away with that.

Comment: I used to have SIGTERM specified in my Supervisor config, but that didn't work either. Due to the nature of the workers, I can't really wait for the children processes to get cleaned up since they may take a very long time to stop. I was hoping that killing the parent would automatically kill any children, but you're saying that's not the default? I'm currently working around this by doing a `kill -9 <pid>` on the Python process, which has been auto-killing any children as well, which is what I thought Supervisor was doing.

Comment: There's a difference between the process hierarchies (A.) bash -> python -> workers, and (B.) python -> workers. Under (A.) we need to worry about what bash does upon hearing SIGTERM. That might be modified by a `trap` statement. Under (B.), achieved via `exec python ...`, bash is completely out of the picture, and python's default signal handler is what matters. I believe python will do the right thing for you, by default.